Azure DevOps - How to specify specific stage deployment for release pipeline on specific date
I'm trying to figure out how to set up scheduled deployment, with a specific stage, and with a specific branch.
Currently, I have our dev stage environment scheduled to deploy release Mon-Fri in the morning using the default branch set with the Build Artifacts.  However, what I'd like to do is set another scheduled release deployment for Tuesday morning, for our UAT stage environment, while using specific feature branch.  I checked this Microsoft documentation, but it tells me how to do it in YAML (but I don't see the option for this in the Release Pipeline).
I know I can just clone the existing pipeline and have it set to that schedule, specific branch and stage, but would prefer to have it in just one Release Pipeline.

I know I can just clone the existing pipeline and have it set to that schedule, specific branch and stage - this might be your best (or only) choice if you're using the classical release pipelines.
I don't see any problem in that as long as you use task groups to reuse the tasks in multiple stages or pipelines.

@Tscott, As mentioned in my answer below, you can can configure Artifact filters and Schedule Triggers on the Pre-deployment conditions of each stage in classic release pipeline.

In classic release pipeline, you can configure Artifact filters and Schedule Triggers on the Pre-deployment conditions of each stage.

The related documentation:

Release triggers (classic) - Stage triggers


EDIT:
To let the Scheduled stage can automatically run, you first need to let the release can be automatically triggered.
You can set the CD trigger on the source build artifact added to the release pipeline.

You can set Build branch filters to let the release can be automatically triggered when the upstream build runs for the specified branches.
If not set the branch filters or set the included branch as '*' on the filters, the release will be triggered when upstream build runs for any branches.


With the CD trigger:

When the upstream build is completed on a branch that can match the Build branch filters set on CD trigger, the release gets automatically triggered.

In the triggered release, the stages which have Schedule set will not start running. They will keep waiting until it reaches the scheduled time.

The stages which does not have Schedule set will start running.


If you manually trigger a release, the stages will have the same behaviors.



This didn't work for me sadly. I set the stage with it's own time and day, but when it came time for those to automatically deploy, nothing happened.

@Tscott, To let the Scheduled stage can automatically run, you first need to let the release can be automatically triggered. For more details, see EDIT in my above answer.

I currently have the 'Schedule Set' enabled.  Should this be disabled?

@Tscott, To run the stage in release pipeline, it must trigger the pipeline at first, then it will evaluate the Schedule set on the stages. The Schedule set on the stage only determine when the stages start running after the release is triggered, it can not automatically trigger the release. To automatically trigger the release, you need to set CD trigger as mentioned above.

@Tscott, If you want a stage can run at a Scheduled time, you should enable Schedule on that stage and specify the time when the stage should start running in the triggered releases.
